# Auto increment version by jdbc batch update

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to insert 1000 record using spring jdbc template batch update to avoid the performance issue  I am trying to insert in batch size of 50. . I have one column where I need to increment version number. For example  If I insert 1000 it should have once version. but version is getting incremented after 50 bcs its getting commited in th db. Please let me know how to handle disable auto commit in spring jdbc template. So that batch run in terms of size 50 every time and commit to database final. So that version will be maintained to 1 for all 1000  record.

Comment: If you configured txs correctly there is no auto-commit. So I actually doubt the problem you have is what you think you have. I suspect the error lies in your own code.

Comment: I am not using @ transaction using Spring jdbc named parameter template.

Comment: The fact that you use the tempalte doesn't mean you sholdn't be using `@Transactional`.

Comment: I want to disable auto commit  so that very insert of 50 record version number should not increment. It should incremnet only if run after 1000 record

Comment: I am increment version by select max version from db

Comment: Read. Enable transactions and you won't have auto-commit. Disabling auto-commit is enabling transactions. Also just insert all 1000 at once using the Spring jdbc batch support, it will be a single insert statement that way which will be faster.